# Why not applied properly in JQuery my calculation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

[link](http://reliancetrustgroup.com/)

It is a problem when accessing the homepage of the website higher resolutions
(On the small is ok).

For example for this resolution (1920x1200) site appears like in the picture below.

**CODE JS:**

```
 var screenH = jQuery(window).height();
 console.log("Inaltimea ecranului este:",screenH);
 var headerH=jQuery('header').outerHeight();
 console.log("Inaltimea headerului este:",headerH);
 var footerH=jQuery('footer').outerHeight();
 console.log("Inaltimea footerului este:",footerH);
 var calcul=screenH-headerH-333-2;
 console.log("Rezultatul este:",calcul);
 jQuery('#main').css( "height", calcul );
```

I put this code in the function window.load function.

But unfortunately it does not work ... I did not realize that my picture is not until the end.

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao95S.jpg)

Comment: Can't you set your image as background and use `background-size: cover` ?

Comment: yes...here  .entry-header img
{
background-size:cover;
}

Comment: `background-size` apply on background, not image. You need to set your image as `background-image` instead of an inline one.

Comment: you've used img on your `<body>` tag as `background` and also have set `background-size: 100% 100%` , set `cover` in place of this and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does work, but it takes some time to get fired. This is the exact reason why you should try to resize the image with css only. background-size should do the job by itself.